# Oracle get checksum value for a data chunk defined by a select clause

Tags: sql, oracle, checksum

Is there any method in SQL (Oracle) using which I can get something like:

```
select checksum(select * from table) from table;
```

Comment: You could try ORA_HASH. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions112.htm#SQLRF06313, and also: http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.ca/2014/05/oracle-table-or-query-checksum-function.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH` for this.  The query results must be ordered and must not contain any LOBs, or the results won't be deterministic.

```
select dbms_sqlhash.gethash(q'[select * from some_table order by 1,2]', digest_type => 1)
from dual;
```

Where digest_type 1 = HASH_MD4, 2 = HASH_MD5, 3 = HASH_SH1.

That package is not granted to anyone by default.  To use it, you'll need someone to logon as SYS and run this:

```
SQL> grant execute on dbms_sqlhash to <your_user>;
```

---

The query results must be ordered, as described in "Bug 17082212 : DBMS_SQLHASH DIFFERENT RESULTS FROM DIFFERENT ACCESS PATH".

I'm not sure why LOBs don't work, but it might be related to the way the function `ORA_HASH` does not work well with LOBs.  [This Jonathan Lewis article](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/ora_hash-function/) includes some examples of `ORA_HASH` returning different results for the same LOB data.  And recent versions of the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions136.htm#SQLRF06313) warn that `ORA_HASH` does not support LOBs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! Any methods without installing DBMS_SQLHASH?

Comment: It's already installed, you just need to grant access to it.  You'll probably need to run some grants no matter which option you go with.  Even packages like DBMS_CRYPTO are often not granted to public.

Comment: Interestingly the last mention of DBMS_SQLHASH in the documentaion is in [10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/appendixb.htm#CHDGHCAE)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yeah the package has always been poorly documented for some reason. It's not listed in the obvious places, but it's listed in the [11g Security Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e16543/data_encryption.htm) and is mentioned in the [20c SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-3C11D3A9-8B14-4DCC-B212-B7FE57EE81E8) as a package that can be replaced by the new CHECKSUM function.